# Cocos2d Using 1 class for multiple enemies Score error

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Thank you for taking the time to look at my question, As I am very new to programming any help or pointers in the right direction is much appreciated.

Overview...
I have a simple game I am trying to create and it includes a class for 'Ball' sprite that is fired from the left of the screen to the right. The speed at which this "Ball" sprite is created is random and each time the "Ball" moves past the right of the screen a point is added to the score.

[image]

Problem....
The problem I have is when 2 "Balls" fire at almost the same time (which happens some times as its random) they pass the right hand of the screen less then a second apart and when this happens it only seems to add 1 when it should be adding 2 to the score (as 2 balls has passed the right side).

Below is the code for my Ball launcher class (use this class to call the ball randomly).

If you have used or gone through 'Ray Wenderlichs' Learn Cocos2D then allot of this will look familiar as after going through his book I have tried to edit his code to do what I want (to me after reading the book its the best way to learn, by messing with the code etc).

```
@implementation BL

@synthesize delegate;
@synthesize lauchingAnim;
@synthesize afterlauchingAnim;

-(void) dealloc {
    delegate = nil;
    [lauchingAnim release];
    [afterlauchingAnim release];

    [super dealloc];
}

//--The below shootPhaser method takes the current direction the launcher is facing and asks the delegate (gameplaylayer) to create the ball moving in that direction.
//--The below createPhaserWithDirection method was declared (created) in the GamePlayLayerDelegate protocol.

-(void)shootPhaser {
    CGPoint phaserFiringPosition;
    PhaserDirection phaserDir;
    CGPoint position = [self position];



    float xPosition = position.x + position.x * 0.51f;
    float yPosition = position.y + position.y * 0.045f;

    {
        phaserDir = kDirectionRight;
    }

    phaserFiringPosition = ccp(xPosition, yPosition);

    [delegate createPhaserWithDirection:phaserDir andPosition:phaserFiringPosition];


}

-(void)changeState:(CharacterStates)newState {
    [self stopAllActions];
    id action = nil;

    characterState = newState;

    switch (newState) {
        case kStatespawning:
           // CCLOG(@“launcher->Changing State to Spwaning");
            [self setDisplayFrame:
             [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]
              spriteFrameByName:@“lancher_1.png"]];
            break;


        case kStateIdle:
           //  CCLOG(@“laucher->Changing state to idle");
            [self setDisplayFrame:
             [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]
              spriteFrameByName:@"lancher_1.png"]];

            break;


        case kStateFiring:
           // CCLOG(@“launcher->Changing State to firing");


            action = [CCSequence actions:
                      [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:lauchingAnim],
                      [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self
                                          selector:@selector(shootPhaser)],
                      [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:afterlauchingAnim],
                      [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:2.0f],
                      nil];


            lauchingAnim.restoreOriginalFrame = NO;
            afterlauchingAnim.restoreOriginalFrame = NO;

            [self changeState:kStateIdle];

            break;



        case kStateDead:
            CCLOG(@“launcher->changing state to dead");

            break;

        default:
            CCLOG(@"unhandled state %d in launcher", newState);
            break;
    }

    if (action !=nil) {
        [self runAction:action];

    }
}

-(void)updateStateWithDeltaTime: (ccTime)deltaTime andListOfGameObjects:(CCArray*)listOfGameObjects {


    if (characterState == kStateFiring) {

        // 5
        if (characterState != kStateFiring) {
            // If RadarDish is NOT already taking Damage
            [self changeState:kStateFiring];
            return;
        }
    }

    if ((([self numberOfRunningActions] == 0) && (characterState != kStateDead)) ) {
       // CCLOG(@"launcher Going to Idle!!!");
        [self changeState:kStateIdle];
        return;
    }

}


-(void)initAnimations {

    [self setLauchingAnim:[self loadPlistForAnimationWithName:@"lauchingAnim" andClassName:NSStringFromClass([self class])]];

    [self setAfterlauchingAnim:[self loadPlistForAnimationWithName:@"afterlauchingAnim" andClassName:NSStringFromClass([self class])]];
}



-(id) initWithSpriteFrameName:(NSString*)frameName{
    if ((self=[super init])) {
        if ((self = [super initWithSpriteFrameName:frameName])) {

            CCLOG(@"### Laauncher initialized");
            [self initAnimations];                                   
            characterHealth = 3.0f;                                
            gameObjectType = kBallLaucher;
            // 3
            [self changeState:kStateIdle];                       

        }
    }
    return self;  
}




@end
```

Below is the code for my "Ball" class...

```
#import “Ball.h"


@implementation Ball


@synthesize delegate;
@synthesize myDirection;
@synthesize travelingAnim;
@synthesize ScoreAnim;

-(void) dealloc {
    delegate = nil;
    [travelingAnim release];
    [ScoreAnim release];
    [super dealloc];

}

-(void)changeState:(CharacterStates)newState {
    [self stopAllActions];
    [self setCharacterState:newState];

   CGSize screenSize1 = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
   CGPoint position = [self position];

   CGPoint endPosition = ccp(screenSize1.width*1.5f, screenSize1.height*0.20f);


    id action = nil;
    //id action1 = nil;

    switch (newState) {
        case kStatespawning:
        CCLOG(@“Spawning Ball");
            [self setDisplayFrame:[[CCSpriteFrameCache
                                    sharedSpriteFrameCache]
                                   spriteFrameByName:@"Ball_1.png"]];

            break;

        case kStateTravelling: {

    movementAction = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:5.0f
                                                 position:endPosition];



            }

            break;


        case kStateScore:

            PLAYSOUNDEFFECT(SCORE);

            CCLOG(@“Ball Past Left Of Screen => Add 1 to Score");

            action = [CCSequence actions:
                      [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(removeSelf)],
                      nil];
            break;


        default:
            CCLOG(@“Ball -> Unknown CharState %d",
                  characterState);

            break;
    }
    if (action !=nil)
        [self runAction:action];
}



-(void)removeSelf{
    CCLOG(@"Removing Ball Object Has Scored.");


    [self setVisible:NO];
    [self removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];

    return;

}


-(void)updateStateWithDeltaTime:(ccTime)deltaTime andListOfGameObjects:(CCArray *)listOfGameObjects {


    CGPoint currentSpitePosition = [self position];

    CGSize screenSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;



    if (currentSpitePosition.x > screenSize.width*1.1f)  {{


             [self changeState:kStateScore];
        }
    }

    return;
    }


    if ([self numberOfRunningActions] == 0) {

        if (characterState == kStatespawning) {
            [self changeState:kStateTravelling];
            return;
        }

}


}

-(void)initAnimations {

    [self setTravelingAnim:[self loadPlistForAnimationWithName:@"travelingAnim" andClassName:NSStringFromClass([self class])]];

    [self setScoreAnim:[self loadPlistForAnimationWithName:@"ScoreAnim" andClassName:NSStringFromClass([self class])]];    
}


-(id) initWithSpriteFrameName:(NSString*)frameName{
    if ((self=[super init])) {
        if ((self = [super initWithSpriteFrameName:frameName])) {

            CCLOG(@"### Ball Initialised");
            [self initAnimations];                                   
            characterHealth = 3.0f;                                
            gameObjectType = kEnemyTypeBall;                    
            [self changeState:kStatespawning];                       

        }
    }
    return self;  
}

@end
```

Below is the code for my "GameplayLayer" class...

```
    #import "GamePlayLayer.h"
#import “Ball.h"
#import “BL.h"

@implementation GamePlayLayer

@synthesize delegate;

-(void) dealloc {
    delegate = nil;
    [super dealloc];
    }


-(void) update:(ccTime)deltaTime {
    CCArray *listOfGameObjects =
    [sceneSpriteBatchNode children];




    for (GameCharacter *tempChar in listOfGameObjects) {         
        [tempChar updateStateWithDeltaTime:deltaTime andListOfGameObjects:listOfGameObjects];                        
    }

    GameCharacter *tempChar = (GameCharacter*)[sceneSpriteBatchNode
                                                getChildByTag:kEnemyTypeBall];


    if ([tempChar characterState] == kStateScore)  <==HERE I AM SEEING IF THE BALL HAS SCORED - THIS IS ALSO WHERE I THINK I MAY BE GOING WRONG SOMEHOW.
    {
        CCLOG(@"Add 1 Points To Score");

        [self addPoint];
        return;
     }

}




-(void)addPoint
{
score = score + 1; 
   [scoreLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%i", score]];   <===ADDING THE POINT TO THE SCORE
return;
}




-(void) createObjectOfType: (GameObjectType)objectType
                withHealth:(int)initialHealth atLocation:(CGPoint)spawnLocation withZValue:(int)ZValue {

if (kBallLaucher == objectType) {
        CCLOG(@"Creating launcher Object");
        BL *ballLauncher = [[[BL alloc] init] initWithSpriteFrameName:@“launcher_1.png"];
        [ballLauncher setCharacterHealth:initialHealth];
        [ballLauncher setPosition:spawnLocation];
        [sceneSpriteBatchNode addChild:tBT z:ZValue tag:kBallLaucher ];
        [ballLauncher setDelegate:self];
        [ballLauncher release];
    }



}

**BELOW IS HOW I CONTROL WHEN THE BALL IS FIRED**

-(void)ChangeStateLaucher:(int)brandnewState withState:(CharacterStates)newState andObject:(GameObjectType)objectType; {


    BL *bL = (BL*)
    [sceneSpriteBatchNode getChildByTag:kBallLaucher];

    int x =  (arc4random() % 2);



    if (x==0) {
    CCLOG(@"Start Laucher Firing");
     [bL changeState:kStateFiring];

        count = 0;        

    }
    if (x==1) {
    CCLOG(@"No Laucher Firing");

      count = count + 1;

        if (count == 2) {
            CCLOG(@"No Laucher Firing x2 - Start Laucher Firing");

            [bL changeState:kStateFiring];

        } else if (count > 3) {
            CCLOG(@"No Laucher Firing x3 - Start Laucher Firing");

            [bL changeState:kStateFiring];

        }
    }


    [delegate ChangeStateLaucher:x withState:kStateFiring andObject:objectType];
    }

-(void)createPhaserWithDirection:(PhaserDirection)phaserDirection andPosition:(CGPoint)spawnPosition {
   CCLOG(@"Creating Ball from Gameplay Layer");
  Ball *ballSprite = [[Ball alloc]initWithSpriteFrame:[[CCSpriteFrameCache
                                                                  sharedSpriteFrameCache]
                                                                 spriteFrameByName:@"Ball_1.png"]];
   [ballSprite setPosition:spawnPosition];
    [ballSprite setMyDirection:phaserDirection];
    [ballSprite setCharacterState:kStatespawning];
    [ballSprite setCharacterHealth:3.0f];
    [sceneSpriteBatchNode addChild:ballSprite z:20  tag:kEnemyTypeBall];

    [ballSprite release];
}



-(id)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self !=nil) {
        CGSize screenSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector]. winSize;

        self.TouchEnabled = YES;

        srandom(arc4random()); // Seeds the random number generator


            [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]
             addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"scene1atlas.plist"];          // 1
            sceneSpriteBatchNode =
            [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"scene1atlas.png"]; // 2




        [self createObjectOfType:kBallLaucher  withHealth:3 atLocation:ccp(screenSize.width * 0.05f, screenSize.height * 0.822f) withZValue:10];




        [gameBeginLabel setPosition:ccp(screenSize.width/2,screenSize.height/2)];          // 2
        [self addChild:gameBeginLabel];                                    // 3
        id labelAction = [CCSpawn actions:
                          [CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:2.5f],
                          nil];                                          // 4
        [gameBeginLabel runAction:labelAction];

        lives = 3;


        scoreLabel = [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:@"$0"
                                            fntFile:@“BallTest.fnt"];

        scoreLabel.position = ccp(screenSize.width * 0.5f, screenSize.height * 0.9f);
        [self addChild:scoreLabel
                     z:-1 tag:kNewScoreTagValue];

        [self scheduleUpdate];

    }
    return self;
}


@end
```

Once again I would like to thank anyone that has taken the time to look at this question regardless if you have posted a pointer or answer or not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that when there are more than one Ball objects on the screen, the `GamePlayLayer` `update` method is unable to pick up on the state change on one of the balls at times because that ball is removed as soon as it enters `kStateScore`.
If you add a certain delay before removing the ball , the update method should pick up the changes in all the balls and your problem should be resolved.

In your `Ball.m` `-(void)changeState:(CharacterStates)newState` function , modify the action on state kStateScore like

```
action = [CCSequence actions:[CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:0.2],
                      [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(removeSelf)],
                      nil];
```

Try this out and let me know if this worked for you!

**EDIT**

The above solution would end up adding more than one point as the ball would remain in kStateScore state for a long time due to delay. In order to counter that problem , we can introduce a new state call kStateDead and change the ball state to kStateDead after adding the point. This will ensure a point is added only once and also we can put the responsibility of removing the ball in kStateDead state. The new code would like as follows :

Ball.m

```
case kStateScore:

            PLAYSOUNDEFFECT(SCORE);

            CCLOG(@“Ball Past Left Of Screen => Add 1 to Score");

            break;

case kStateDead:

        action = [CCSequence actions:
                      [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(removeSelf)],
                      nil];

        default:
            CCLOG(@“Ball -> Unknown CharState %d",
                  characterState);

            break;
```

and in your Gameplayer.m

```
if ([tempChar characterState] == kStateScore)  <==HERE I AM SEEING IF THE BALL HAS SCORED - THIS IS ALSO WHERE I THINK I MAY BE GOING WRONG SOMEHOW.
    {
        CCLOG(@"Add 1 Points To Score");

        [self addPoint];
        [tempChar changeState:kStateDead]; //change the state to dead after the point is added
        return;
     }
```

Comment: Good Morning Abhineet, firstly thank you for your reply above. I have attempted to use the solution you have posted but because of the delay the method in my gameplaylayer class stays true for longer so it does not just add 1 to the score, it adds anywhere between 3 to 6 points. Also because of this I can't really tell if its working (don't know if the 6 points just added are because thats the random score number this time or because it has registered both the balls). Thank you again so much for attempting to help me.

Comment: @Robnoob apologies for the delay in response and for the incorrect post. I clearly did not think it through. However, i have updated the answer. let me know if this works for you. Cheers

Comment: I also apologise for the long reply (not had much spare time of late to learn), used your solution above and it works! Thank you so much for your help on this!!